# Http Request not sent from android C#

Tags: c#, android, httpwebrequest, xamarin

Iam developing a cross platform android app in Xamarin. I want to send a request to register my device. Iam sending my `DeviceId`, `DeviceName` and `EncodedAccountName` i.e my email id. 
But I dont get any response. I have tested the request on `Postman` and get a proper response.

Here is my code:

```
StringBuilder registerContent = new StringBuilder();

        registerContent.Append("DeviceId=").Append(deviceId).Append("&");
        registerContent.Append("Name=").Append(deviceName).Append("&");
        registerContent.Append("EncodedAccountName‏=").Append(username);



WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(EndPoints.RegisterDeviceEndPoint);
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = registerContent.ToString();
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType= "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();// Dont get any response here
            // Display the status.
            System.Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream(); 
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            System.Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();

            return response.ToString();
```

Any ideas on what might me going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "dont get any response"? Does it return a null reference? Does it not return at all? Does it return a response with no content?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes it gives me a `null

Comment: Looks like you are creating a GET method, not a POST. Try Yoav's version as it should work much better.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I notify my `Web API` and wait for a `string` response:

```
string myParameters = "?firstParam=" + someParam1 + "&secondParam=" + someParam2;

string url = someHTTPAddress + myParameters;
stringResponseFromWebAPI = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(url);
```